# Java regex pattern to find 3 letters palindrome in a input string

Tags: java, regex

Im trying to find regex pattern in java to find if a string includes a 3 letter palindrome like :

- 1. goingfor**eye**checkup
- 2. **nan** means not a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a **three letter** palindrome you may use the following pattern:

```
^(?=.*([a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]\1)[a-zA-Z .]+$
```

- `^` Assert position beginning of string.
- `(?=.*([a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]\1)` Positive lookahead. Ensure that at some point in the string there is a letter (`([a-zA-Z])`), which is followed by a different letter (`[a-zA-Z]`)  and then the same letter again (`\1`).
- `[a-zA-Z .]+` Character set for letters, whitespace and `.`, one or more `+`.
- `$` Assert position end of string.

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/nkqjte/1).

---

For test strings:

- `goingforeyecheckup` Matched because of **eye**.
- `nan means not a number.` Matched because of **nan**.
- `do not match her` Not matched as there is no palindrome.
- `match here` Matched because of **ere**.

Comment: This is what exactly I need.. Thank you..You made my day

Comment: Great to hear, you are welcome.

Comment: it is not working yet. i just click the link you provided, however it only machets `e` of `eye` , `n` of `nan`. what is wrong?

Comment: @TheScientificMethod You are mistaken. The `e` is in the capturing group but the entire string is matched.

Comment: i got it. so the requirement is to match the line with palindrom, not the palidrom word itself. i thought to match the palindrom word.

Comment: Correct, the first line in the question states that: *to find if a string includes a 3 letter palindrome*